# Swift === with nil

Tags: swift

Why does the following not work in Swift?

```
if someObject === nil {
}
```

You have to do the test using the == operator such as

```
if someObject == nil {
}
```

I was thinking that === was more like making sure the instances where the exact same (basically comparing the pointers) and == was more like an isEqual check.  Thus I would think === would be more appropriate for testing against nil, but I am obviously incorrect.

The documentation states:

> === or “Identical to” means that two constants or variables of class type
> refer to exactly the same class instance.
>
> == or “Equal to” means that two instances are considered “equal” or “equivalent”
> in value, for some appropriate meaning of “equal”, as defined by the type’s designer.”

Comment: The following works for me `class Person {}
let p = Person()
let q : Person? = nil
println(p === nil)
println(q === nil)`

Comment: The object would have a value of nil, not refer to exactly the same object as nil, which is what === means.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It works exactly like you expect:

```
var s: String? = nil
s === nil // true
```

The only caveat is that to compare to `nil`, your variable *must able to be* `nil`. This means that it must be an optional, denoted with a `?`.

`var s: String` is not allowed to be `nil`, so would therefore always returns `false` when `===` compared to `nil`.

Comment: There is one other caveat - it must an optional of a class type. Not an `Int?` for example.

Comment: That makes a ton sense.  Thank you so much for the great answer.

Comment: @Sulthan Can you explain your statement? Is Int not a class type?

Comment: @Boon In Swift, there are class types (class) and value types (structs, enums). `Int` is not a class type, it's a value type. `===` operator is defined only for class types (and also for `Array` but that's a special case). Therefore, you cannot use `===` for `Int` variables.

Comment: Thank you Sulthan.  You said Array is a special case, do you mean Array is a value type that works with ===?

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct would be that `nil` is not a class instance, but a reference. So `someObject` cannot be an equivalent class instance to `nil`.