# Why I can't use 'object== nil' in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have simple method (hope the syntax is right)

```
func  foo() -> WmGroupItemSample?{

        var sample:WmGroupItemSample?

        if(a > 0){ // some condition
            sample = mGroupItemSampleList[0]
        }
        else{
           // do nothing
        }

        return sample
    }
```

As I understand `foo` method might return nil if statement `a>0` doesn't occur. Therefore return type is: `WmGroupItemSample?`.

My doubts are in place where I call this method:

```
var sample:WmGroupItemSample? = foo()

    if let temp = sample{
        return sample.getStartDate()
    }
    else{
         return -1
    }
```

Is this proper way to validate *if not nil*? I use Beta 6

What difference if I'll call without `?` or with `!` like:

```
var sample:WmGroupItemSample = foo()
```

or:

```
var sample:WmGroupItemSample! = foo()
```

**Why I can't validate `sample` like:**

```
if sample == nil {
   /* do one*/
 }
else {

}
```

Comment: ? means that the value can be nil whereas ! is unwrapping the value so you has to be sure it is not nil if you do not want to have an runtime error

Comment: Are you sure the second case is compiling? I haven't seen it ... yet. The first means a variable can be nil so the foo can return nil.

Comment: Literally all of this is covered in the documentation.  You'd have a more official, more complete understanding of Swift optionals if you just looked there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a substitute for reading the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To compare value with a nil it has to be allowed to be a nil by `?` mark. This means that the value can (possibly) be a `nil`. So by default:

```
var a : String
```

can not be a nil. To allow a string be a nil you have to do:

```
var a : String?
```

calling variable with `!` is unwrapping an optional value

> "Trying to use ! to access a non-existent optional value triggers a
>   runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil
>   value before using ! to force-unwrap its value." Excerpt From: Apple
>   Inc. "The Swift Programming Language."

iBooks. https://itun.es/pl/jEUH0.l

For more information I would suggest:

- [basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)
- [more advanced](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

reading. Also that [SO question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314646/swift-with-nil) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to implement either the Equatable or Comparable protocols.
implementing the Equatable protocol using a global function

```
func ==<T>(lhs:T, rhs: T?)-> Bool{
return lhs == nil 
}
```

// in your class you can now extend the Equatable protocol in the class definition. ie

```
class ClassName: Equatable{
   // properties and functions
}
```